# Tokenize a String on multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

I want to tokenize a String to key value pairs. But key has characters like underscore, comma, space etc. The key value pair is separated by = character

Example:

> key=value start_time="2013-03-01 03:20:40" Key withspace=space1 two
>   withspace=space2 key=value key-key key=value key_underscore=500058
>   key=value - value key= value_value

Desired output is

> Key=value
>   start_time="2013-03-01 03:20:40"
>   Key withspace=space1
>   two withspace=space2
>   key-key key=value
>   key_underscore=500058
>   key=value - value
>   key= value_value

And this helps me to populate the value in a map and put it in a table.

Can i use any existing methods like StringTokenizer, Patter, String.split() etc. Or should i write my own String parser to get this type of output.

Just want to check some best methods to acheive this

Comment: Start with this: ["`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split()` takes a regex. If you can put in a regex to match your set of keys, you can use it

Answer (score 1):

Key with spaces will not work, at least with the given rules. `key=value - value key= value_value` is ambiguos. The last key-value pair can be extracted as `key = value_value` or `value key= value_value`.